# Rails is not parsing _method and authenticity_token form data fiels

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, axios

I'm using axios to send requets and my current task is to send request for DELETing user. so i made a button and a function that triggers on click.

```
 sendRequest(e) {
    const token = document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").getAttribute('content');

    axios.post('/users/2', {
      _method: 'DELETE',
      authenticity_token: token,
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });

}
```

According to rails docs:

> When parsing POSTed data, Rails will take into account the special
>   _method parameter and act as if the HTTP method was the one specified inside it ("DELETE" in this example).

But after sending the request, i've got an error in console:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/2"):`

**UPD 1:**

Just tried simple $.ajax request:

```
const token = document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").getAttribute('content');

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/users/2.json",
  data: { _method: "delete", authenticity_token: token }
})
 .done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 })
```

and it works great. What's the difference than between axios post and ajax post requests so rails woun't parse axios `_method` field?

Comment: why don't you use `axios.delete`?

Comment: @artgb the same thing when using axios.delete but with authenticity_token. But anyway, i want to figure it out why it's not working with post request and _method field. Maybe i'm missing something?